# How to exclude the folders proc and sys from search with find command ?

Tags: command-line, find

I wanted to execute a script that picks out a random directory path:

```
find / -type d | shuf -n1
```

Unfortunately I get error messages about the prohibition of entering certain directories.

**How can I exclude a directory from the search with find ?**

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To exclude specific paths, on Linux:

```
find / -path /sys -prune -o -path /proc -prune -o -type d
```

Another approach is to tell `find` not to recurse under different filesystems.

```
find / -xdev -type d
```

You could also use [locate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locate_(Unix)) to query a database of file names (usually updated nightly, you could also update it manually using `updatedb`) instead of the live system.

```
locate '*' | shuf -n 1
```

Comment: great, short and insightful. find / -xdev -type d itself works, but find / -xdev -type d | shuf -n 1 displays error messages.

Comment: @AbdulAlHazred you haven't said what messages but I'm guessing they're "permission denied" errors. Either run the command as root or just ignore the errors by sending them to stderr: `find / -xdev -type d 2>/dev/null`.

Comment: Couldn't you just do `find / \( -path /sys -o -path /proc \) -prune -o -type d` Would be useful if you want to exclude more dirs like `/dev` or `/tmp`, etc.

Answer (score 8):

with GNU find you may also use regex options, e. g. like this:

```
find / -regextype posix-extended -regex "/(sys|srv|proc)" -prune -o -type d
```

Comment: that's the nicest approach, by far (rant: so there's a gnu option that makes find / usable on gnu linux like on any other OS that didn't have a shitty /proc implementation ;-)

Answer (score 1):

One method is to only **include** real filesystems.

Determine all mount points for real filesystems, and put them on one line:

```
$ realfs=$(df -x tmpfs -x devtmpfs | tail -n +2 | awk '{print $6;}' | xargs)
$ echo $realfs
/ /home /dos /Data
```

Run `find` only against those mount points.

```
$ find ${realfs} -type d |& grep -v "Permission denied" | shuf -n1
/Data/share/source/pan2/.git/refs/tags
```

(`|&` is a bashism added to 4.x -- works for me on 4.4.)